# Regular Expression for all non letter changes to underscore remain fixed first letter # intact

Tags: regex

I use this regex for changing all symbols or any non digit character to underscore remaining first # value as it is.

```
text.replace(/(?!^)[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/gu, '_');
```

This will working fine but for bengali letter when user type `চার`  it prints like that: `চ__া_র`

Please provide me the correct regex.

Comment: Right, you need `/(?!^)[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]+/gu`

Comment: Wiktor Stribizew this is okay but first # value also changed to underscore but i need not to change the first # value

Comment: See the demo in the answer below, no other change happens.

Comment: So, have you tried it the way shown in the answer? Please showcase any issues with that approach, I do not see any now.

Answer (score 2):

The second char (`\u09BE`) is a **09BE BENGALI VOWEL SIGN `AA`** that belongs to a  "Mark, spacing combining" Unicode category (`Mc`).

That means, you need to add a diacritic mark Unicode category class to the negated character class:

```js
/(?!^)[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]+/gu
```

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
console.log("চার".replace(/(?!^)[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]+/gu, '_'))
```